# I can't find the source of the code in the WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am new to WordPress. I downloaded a theme and  I need to change the codes of the theme. I couldn't find where col-lg-3 came from in the header.php.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RmN3.png)

do_action( 'bizzmo_before_header' );

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrJiH.png)

I can't find where "bizzmo_before_header" is. Not in functions.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you find the class , you are looking for

Path:

```
/wp-content/themes/bizzmo/inc/custom-hooks/header-hooks.php:
```